# React native toggle button with text

Tags: react-native, react-toggle

I am new to react-native. I want a toggle button with 2 text blocks. How this can be achieved with react native?.
The toggler should animate when clicking buy and sell texts respectively.

Following is the image reference for the design.

[image: Image Reference]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this library](https://github.com/mymai91/react-native-toggle-element).
This does not match the design exactly but it's a toggle with two text blocks. If you want something that looks exactly like your image I'm afraid you will have to build it yourself. You could use the mentioned library as a starting point.